# xmlDocumentElement is not defined

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Here is my code: 
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="foodstore.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="process()">
        <h3>WELCOME to our online food store</h3>
        Please type what you want to order:
        <input type="text" id="userinput" ></input>
        <div id="underInput"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
 <?php
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>";
echo '<response>';
            $food = $_GET['food'];
            $foodArray = array('tuna','bacon','beef','loaf','mutton');
            if(in_array($food,$foodArray))
                echo 'We do have'.' '.$food;
            elseif($food=='')
                echo 'type something dude!';
            else
                echo 'Sorry we dont sell'.' '.$food;
echo '</response>';
?>
```

JS

```
var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();

function createXmlHttpRequestObject()
    {
        var xmlHttp;

        if(window.ActiveXObject)
            {
                try
                    {
                        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                catch(e)
                    {
                        xmlHttp = false;
                    }
            }
        else if(window.XMLHttpRequest) 
            {
                try
                    {
                        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    }
                catch(e)
                    {
                        xmlHttp = false;
                    }
            }

        if(!xmlHttp)
            {
                alert('cannot connect to database!');
            }
        else
            {
                return xmlHttp;
            }
    }

function process()
    {
        if(xmlHttp.readyState == 0 || xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
            {
                food = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("userinput").value);
                xmlHttp.open("GET", "ajax.php?food=" + food, true);
                xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
                xmlHttp.send(null);
            }
        else
            {
                setTimeOut('process()',1000);
            }
    }


function handleServerResponse()
    {
        if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
            {
                if(xmlHttp.status==200)
                    {
                        xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
                        xmlDocumnetElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;
                        message = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;
                        document.getElementById("underInput").innerHtml = "<span style='color:blue'" + message + "</span>";
                        setTimeOut('process()',1000);
                    }
            }
        else
            {
                alert('something went wrong');
            }
    }
```

Everything seems to be fine to me but I still keep getting the error 'xmlDocumentElement is not defined'. Seems like this is an error due to some parsing issues within javascript and php.. Please help me fix this error. thanks

Comment: spell mistake there `xmlDocumnetElement = xmlResponse.documentElement`

Comment: @legendinmaking alias "eagle eyes" :P

Comment: ok now im getting another error 'setTimeOut is not defined' on line 66

Comment: can't you simply  `setTimeout(process, 1000);`

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
window.setTimeOut('process', 1000);
```